# Vue module is not compiling

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, vue.js

I am following a YouTube tutorial, Todo List App with Laravel and Vue.js and 27 minutes I come across the following problem when running in the terminal 'npm run hot':

webpack compiled with 1 error
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js 4:0-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './vue/app' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\todolist2\resources\js'

The problem occurs on file app/resources/js/app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue'

import App from './vue/app'

const app = new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    components: {App}
});
```

File structure is

js
---vue/app.vue
app.js

I have run npm install beforehand and Vue is in the  app/node_modules folder

Any ideas on how I can fix? Thank you!

Comment: I didn't understand about app/node_modules path. Do you mean your node_modules folder is inside the app folder, not in the root path?

Comment: Apologies, Emtiaz! The node_modules is in the root path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `webpack.mix.js` add `.vue()` in the end like this

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]).vue();
```